# MySQL Memory Considerations

Tags: mysql, memory

I am pretty new to MySQL and a server with 8GB of RAM. I figure I should do some high level tuning of the memory, but I don't really know where to begin. I poked around the internet but didn't find anything that was presented really well. Does any one have a source that they would highly recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your server performing poorly or failing to scale?  If it isn't, I'm not sure I would worry about it yet.

Comment: @Michael It isn't performing badly yet. I just know when I set up Tomcat and Apache, they had natural memory limitations and after lots of debugging I found out I needed to modify variables to allow the JVM to consume more memory. It was my hopes to stem off similar problems with MySQL, but it sounds like that isn't a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your server has been running under normal load, the Perl script at http://mysqltuner.pl/ does a nice job looking at your statistics and figuring out what changes would be recommended. But at @Michael commented, prematurely adjusting your parameters is largely a crapshoot until you actually know where your bottlenecks are.